# BizTalk Adapter to integrate with Oracle E-Business Suite on Oracle Cloud?

Tags: biztalk, oracle-ebs, biztalk-2016

What choices are there to have BizTalk talk to Oracle E-business Suite hosted in the cloud?

Today's BizTalk integration uses OracleDB adapter. I'd like to understand what adapter to use in the new scenario when database servers are not on premises anymore...

Requirements are to be able to poll Oracle EBS Cloud for changes (row/item level) to forward those to other systems, and to be able to send updates when other systems says so (row/item level).

Ideal would have been to use a queueus (like Azure Service Bus Messaging), but that requires Oracle Integration Cloud, with additional licensing fees that I can't argue for because they don't want additional integration plattforms that can't handle other, on-premise integrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic case of a hybrid integration which sounds completely feasible in your environment. I think of following patters using BizTalk, Logic Apps and Service Bus

1) With Logic Apps and BizTalk

You pull the messages from your oracle database using Azure Logic Apps([Get started with the Oracle Database connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-oracledatabase))

You push those messages to the BizTalk using logic app to BizTalk ([Install and use the Logic App Adapter on BizTalk Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/logic-app-adapter)) (Note: You can receive and send the messages from logic apps to and receive from BizTalk)

2) With Logic Apps, BizTalk and ServiceBus

In this approach, your logic app pulls the messages from the oracle database and then pushes the messages on a service bus and BizTalk receives and sends message to this service bus topic/queue

I would suggest you to refer few of the articles below

[Hybrid integration with BizTalk Server and Azure](https://integration.team/blog/hybrid-integration-biztalk-server-azure/)

[Unlocking Azure Hybrid Integration with BizTalk Server](https://notetoself.tech/2017/10/21/unlocking-azure-hybrid-integration-with-biztalk-server/)

Update:

A thing to note here is that the Oracle connector in logic app will connect to an oracle database on premises present over a VM. In cases it is made available as database as a service, then you can add azure function to the mix

Comment: Will Azure Logic Apps Oracle Database Connector be able to call Oracle's cloud and retreive/send data?

Comment: Is there a VPN or express route connectivity to the Oracle database or is it exposed over internet(which I highl doubt)

Comment: Plan A is to have exposed over internet, at least that is what Oracle suggests (no private cloud). I am investigating possibilities for Oracle cloud services to open VPN channel to/from it.

Comment: Okay, I am not sure how secure the oracle cloud would make it while exposing over internet, but you can also explore the options that I have suggested above

Comment: Thanks! I have learned that the Azure Logic Apps Oracle Database connector is used for connecting to on-premises Oracle databases, using a locally installed gateway. So, that is not what I need.

I have used Azure Service Bus as queueu from BizTalk before with success!

Comment: That is correct!! My assumption was that it was available over a VM. In such cases where it is not possible using logic apps, then you add azure functions to the mixture. I have updated my answer to reflect this option too